# Magento 2: Safest way to delete spam customers specific date/email using MySQL?

Tags: magento2, database, customer

what is the safest way to delete spam customers specific date/email using MySQL?

For example delete all customers with email example.com and from 9/15/2018 to 9/28/2018

I cant use back-end UI to delete the records because hosting limitation resources and its gives.

```
Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=28451 in /home/got52/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

So anyone have the mysql query doing that?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to delete it directly from the database ?

Comment: Using sql query ?

Comment: @AdityaShah Yes, but in safest way.

Comment: Yeah try select query first to see if it will delete the correct rows

Comment: please mark as right if it solves your query.

Comment: Hello are you there?

Answer (score 0):

> [Note]: Please take database backup prior to executing these queries.

First check Query using `SELECT` - to see if it will delete the **correct rows**

```
SELECT * from customers
WHERE email like '%example.com'
and date_created between CAST('2018-09-15' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-09-28' AS DATE);
```

**Then**

```
DELETE customers
where email like '%example.com'
and date_created between CAST('2018-09-15' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-09-28' AS DATE);
```

**Customer tables**

```
`customer_address_entity`;
`customer_address_entity_datetime`;
`customer_address_entity_decimal`;
`customer_address_entity_int`;
`customer_address_entity_text`;
`customer_address_entity_varchar`;
`customer_entity`;
`customer_entity_datetime`;
`customer_entity_decimal`;
`customer_entity_int`;
`customer_entity_text`;
`customer_entity_varchar`;
`customer_grid_flat`;
`customer_log`;
`customer_log`;
`customer_visitor`;
```

**Just run query ONLY - which table has email address field.**

Comment: What about if there is another tables stored same data for deleted customers?